# The selector "app-about" did not match any elements

Tags: angular

why I have such a mistake:

```
AboutComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: The selector "app-about" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:2805)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/esm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.js:495)
    at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.js:15257)
    at createElement (core.js:10531)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13688)
    at createRootView (core.js:13616)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15041)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14324)
    at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11218)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4011)
```

my code:

about/about.component.html:

```
<div class="signin-content" >    
    <mat-card >     
        <mat-card-content></mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

about/about.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

where should I add 'app-about' ?

in the 'Sources' tab, highlights me:

```
 <app-about></app-about>
```

Comment: `AboutComponent` is part of the NgModule? Where are you trying to call `<app-about>`?

Answer (score 0):

yes:

app.moduls.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AppMaterialModule} from './app-material/app-material.module';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {AuthService} from './auth/auth.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth.guard';

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import './rxjs-operators';
import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,     
    HomeComponent,   
    AboutComponent,
    LoginComponent,   
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,      
    HttpModule 
  ],

  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, AboutComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: solved task. I deleted the parameter AboutComponent from : 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]